# How to install QHotkey on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint

I wanted to install QHotkey because I need it for a program. However, None of the installation methods worked for me.

I have to install it via qpm. I tried to compile QPM from source but it needs Go. I have NO experince with Go. When I execute the commands to built it from source, nothing happends. No error codes, no new folders, nothing.
https://github.com/Cutehacks/qpm#installing here is the GitHub Repo. I am Using Linux Mint 20.1

Comment: What installation methods? How did you try? How did they fail? Any error messages? What version of Linux Mint are you using? Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Otherwise, we will waste your time and ours giving you solutions you have already tried.

Comment: @terdon I did edit it

Comment: Did you try downloading the pre-compiled binary: https://www.qpm.io/

Comment: @ajgringo619 When I click on the link it redirects me to the GitHub "Compile it from source" section

Comment: Interesting...mine shows this command to download the binary and install it: `curl -O https://www.qpm.io/download/v0.11.0/linux_386/qpm && install -m 755 ./qpm /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Okay that worked for me. Thanks